# list of indices in 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array that looks like this:

```
 [[[ -1.,  1.,  -1.,  1.,  -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

 [[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1., 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.]],

 [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]]
```

I have a list of 3 indices

```
[2,3,4]
```

I would like to get only the "rows" where those indices are zero. So the mask would look like this:

```
[False, True, True]
```

And the result I am looking for would just be the two "rows" which satisfy the condition:

```
 [[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1., 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.]],

 [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]]
```

I put "rows" in quotes because I understand that there is an extra dimension in there - but it needs to stay.

======================EXTENDED EXAMPLE==================

```
a = [[[0,1,0]], [[0,0,0]], [[1,1,1]], [[1,0,1]], [[0,0,1]], [[1,0,0]]]
b = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
c = f(a,b)

For f(a,b)
the first element, [[0,1,0]] is skipped because it has a 0 in the 0th position
the second element, [[0,0,0]] is likewise omitted because because there is a 0 in the 1st position
The third element, [[1,1,1]] is included because it does not have a 0 in the 2nd index position
... and so on...
until the final result is...
c = [[[1, 1, 1]], [[1, 0, 1]], [[1, 0, 0]]
```

So I am looking for f()

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by _row_?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I'm throwing another example up that should make it more clear

Comment: how is `b` used in this example?

Comment: @makis - b is the index for inspection. Here I will use variables: if b = [1,3,2], then the locations we are inspecting are [[[_,HERE,_,_]],[[_,_,_,HERE]],[[_,_,HERE,_]]] - does that make sense?

Comment: ya you got it - cheers

Comment: Are these numpy arrays, or plain Python lists?

Comment: Numpy arrays. Makis's answer works, but it loops. I am hunting now for a faster solution that makes use of numpy functions and thus is run in C++ on the backend and is computed in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

**The most pythonic way (my way to go).**

```
c = [a[i] for i,j in enumerate(b) if a[i][0][j] == 1]

print(c)
[[[1, 1, 1]], [[1, 0, 1]], [[1, 0, 0]]]
```

---

**Solution 2:**

```
a = [[[0,1,0]], [[0,0,0]], [[1,1,1]], [[1,0,1]], [[0,0,1]], [[1,0,0]]]
b = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]

c=[]
for i,j in enumerate(b):
    if a[i][0][j] == 1:
        c.append(a[i])

print(c)
[[[1, 1, 1]], [[1, 0, 1]], [[1, 0, 0]]]
```